# Google Scholar referring to broken link with deleted ResearchGate article

Tags: google-scholar

Here is the timeline of events:

1. A recent paper of mine was posted on ResearchGate (RG).
2. The RG link was picked up by Google Scholar (GS).
3. The RG article was deleted (this was already 2 months ago now).
4. My article still appears in GS, but GS is still using the old, and now broken, link. When it tries to access this link it redirects to the RG home page.

I would like GS to correctly refer to the article, either using a new RG link or the link to the article via publisher.

Has anyone had a similar experience? Do you know how long generally the Google Scholar crawlers take to fix broken links (and if they ever do fix broken links)? Also, because it redirects to the RG home page maybe it's not even detected as a broken link?

After some digging, it looks like Google Scholar's help/support is non-existent. And it is not possible to restore a deleted ResearchGate article.

Here is the broken link, which automatically redirects to the ResearchGate homepage: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Cara-Steger/publication/360977657_Integrating_Equity_Considerations_into_Agent-Based_Modeling_A_Conceptual_Framework_and_Practical_Guidance/links/6296589c55273755ebc63c52/Integrating-Equity-Considerations-into-Agent-Based-Modeling-A-Conceptual-Framework-and-Practical-Guidance.pdf

Here is the Google Scholar entry: https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=t9WLfKQAAAAJ&citation_for_view=t9WLfKQAAAAJ:kNdYIx-mwKoC

And here is the article at the publisher: https://www.jasss.org/25/3/1.html

Comment: Sounds more like a ResearchGate issue - for all Google knows, RG messed up the link. Not quite sure how a web crawler can correlate an old RG link with some new article somewhere else. GS does the best it can with whatever info it can find crawling around, but it is not a replacement for something like Web of Science.

Comment: I don't know if it will work, but if possible in your situation you could try uploading the paper at another source, e.g. arXiv. This could result in the arXiv link appearing as the main link.